# Resolving a library projects SASS files from an application in the same workspace?

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, angular-cli, ng-packagr

Is it possible to resolve SASS contained in a workspace library using an approach that is similar to resolving `ts` files from an application within the same workspace?  For context I'll setup a real workspace as follows:

```
ng new theme-workspace --create-application=false
cd theme-workspace
ng g library theme
mkdir projects/theme/src/lib/styles
touch projects/theme/src/lib/styles/index.scss
ng g application playground
```

Within the directory `projects/theme/src/lib/styles` we will add the following content to `index.scss`.

```
$color: red;
```

And in order to include the style assets we need to update `ng-package.json` with an `asset` block like this:

```
  "assets": [
    { "input": "src/lib/styles", "glob": "**/*.scss", "output": "styles" }
  ]
```

If we build this project library like this:

```
ng build theme
```

We see that `dist/theme/styles` contains `index.scss`.

We can access the generated `ts` component `ThemeComponent` like this from the playground.

```
import { ThemeComponent } from 'theme';
```

When using `@use` to import the SASS `index.scss` module is it possible to use a similar namespace?

For example if we try this from the playground `styles.scss` module it fails:

```
@use `theme/styles` as t;
```

This is the error.

```
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │ @use 'theme/styles' as t;
```

Now we could resolve by using a relative file import, but I'm curious whether there's a "Shorthand" way of doing it that uses the library name space?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/25311

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not supported, but there is a [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/23552) for it.